# Facebook marketing ads api not returning spend for paused campaigns

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to fetch all my campaigns in specific ad account and i want to return the spend for each campaign but the api only returns the running campaign spending however the paused campaign only the name. here is the api i am using

act_ad_account_id/campaigns?fields=name,insights{spend},effective_status{vec},spend_cap&date_preset=last_year

Answer (score 0):

As the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-insights/) state, under the voice **spend**:

> The estimated total amount of money you've spent on your campaign, ad
> set or ad during its schedule. This metric is estimated.

That means that the value is returned when the campaign/adset/ads is actually *scheduled*, so that the api does not return any value when the campaign is set on **PAUSED** because the spend is actually null (or zero).

Comment: The paused campaigns doesn't have the spend field. Even if i get the dates of the paused campaigns when they were active

Comment: Ok so is my answer correct?

Comment: No i need to see my past ads total spent even if it's paused. How to do it

Comment: @ka7ky I'm wondering the same. Were you able to figure it out?